# Why is the copy assignment method not been called?

Tags: c++

Am wondering why the copy assignment operator is not been called and yet the assignment seems to happen? This is my code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

   class String{
       public:
            String(){ std::cout << "Empty Ctor" << '\n'; }
            String(const char* s):data{(char*)s}{ std::cout << "Args Ctor"; }
            Strin& operator=(const String&);
            char* showData(){ return *data; }
       private:
             char* data;
    };

    String& String::operator=(const String& s){
        std::cout << "Copy Assignment" << '\n'; // <- This is NEVER printed
        delete [] data;
        data = new char[strlen(s.data)+1];
        strcpy(data, s.data);
        return *this;
    }

    int main(){
        String* s1 = new String("Hello");
        String* s2 = new String("World");

        s2 = s1;   // This should call the overloaded copy assignment operator!?

        std::cout << s2->showData() << '\n'; // prints "Hello"

        return 0;
    }
```

The **cout** in the assignment operator is not been printed

**Updating my code - based on earlier suggestions. This works as expected**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class String{
    public:
        String():data{nullptr}{ std::cout << "Empty ctor" <<'\n' ;}

        String(const char* s)
        { 
            std::cout<< "Const Args ctor" <<'\n' ;
            data = new char[strlen(s)+1];
            strcpy(data, (char *)s);
        }

        String(const String& other){
            std::cout << "Copy Ctor" << '\n';
            *this = other;
        }

        String& operator=(const String& s){
            std::cout << "Assignment" << '\n';

            if (&s != this){
                delete [] data;
                data = new char[strlen(s.data)+1];
                strcpy(data, s.data);
            }

            return *this;
        }

        ~String(){
            std::cout << "Dtor" << '\n';
            delete [] data;
        }

        char* showData(){ return data; }
    private:
        char* data;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main" << '\n';
    String a("A: Hello");
    std::cout << a.showData() <<'\n';

    String b("B: World"); 
    std::cout << b.showData() <<'\n';

    b = a;   

    std::cout << b.showData() <<'\n';

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s2 = s1;   // This should call the overloaded copy assignment operator!?` Nope, this only assigns one pointer to another. Did you mean `*s2 = *s1;`?

Comment: Any sound reason why you're using raw pointers and `new` at all?

Comment: Not at all, just testing some old code.

Comment: `String(const char* s):data{(char)s}{ std::cout << "Args Ctor"; }` it shouldn't compile, because you cannot assign value type (`char`) to pointer type (`char*`). Also, casting `const char*` to `char` is bad idea and compiler will usually give you a warning or even compilation error.

Comment: code does not compile.

Comment: sorry typo, should be: String(const char* s): data{(char *)s}{std::cout << "Args Ctor"; }

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code provided is not a [mcve].   It includes typos that make it invalid.  Also, looking at answers provided and the OP's response, it appears the OP's actual code has little relationship to the code posted here.   As such, anyone attempting to answer is simply wasting their time, having to guess what the OP's problem actually is.

Answer (score 2):

`s2 = s1;` is just assignment between pointers, it won't call the copy assignment operator, just makes `s2` pointing to the same object pointed by `s1`.

You might want to try with `*s2 = *s1;`, which uses the copy assignment operator of `String`. But you don't need the raw pointer indeed, you can just

```
String s1("Hello");
String s2("World");

s2 = s1;   // This would call the overloaded copy assignment operator

std::cout << s2.showData() << '\n'; // prints "Hello"
```

Comment: @songyaunyao, still I don't see the **cout** statement in the operator assignment method been printed

Comment: @gath I tried a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j60cBFBWDKCHwG33).

Answer (score 2):

"s2 = s1;   // This should call the overloaded copy assignment operator!?"

No. It should not.

You are just assigning the value of one pointer variable to another. No copy assignment of your objects the pointers *point to* is happening.

This would do as you expect:

```
String s1("Hello");
String s2("World");
s1 = s2;
```

As would

```
*s1 = *s2;
```

in your original code.

Comment: When I change to this, nothing gets printed at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets start with this, pointer is not a string, it is a pointer (that points to a string).

So this:

```
String* s1 = new String ("BLE");
```

is creating a string somewhere in memory, and the point that will point to it. So a representation of it is:

```
     +--------+
s -> | 0x005  |----+
     +--------+     \
                     \
                      \
                       \
                        \
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |   |   |   |   | B | L | E |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     0x 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

This:

```
  String* s2;
  s2 = s1;
```

makes `s2` pointing to same address (holding the same value at assign location for the pointer):

```
     +--------+
s1-> | 0x005  |+
     +--------+ \
                 \
     +--------+   \
s2-> | 0x005  |----+
     +--------+     \
                     \
                      \
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |   |   |   |   | B | L | E |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     0x 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Operator `=` in `String` is for type String not for the pointer, so if you have something like this:

```
String s1 = "BLA";
String s2 = s1;
```

This creates brand new object and copies data over to that new object.

I suggest you read *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++* chapter 18.5.

I also believe you have a lot of errors in your code. You cannot do what you are doing.

Here is sample of your code which actually uses copy assignment:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class String{
   public:
        String() : data {new char[1]} { std::cout << "Empty Ctor\n" << '\n'; }
        String(const char* s):data{new char[strlen(s)]}{ strcpy (data, s); std::cout << "Args Ctor\n"; }
        String& operator=(const String&);
        char* showData(){ return data; }
   private:
         char* data;
};

String& String::operator=(const String& s){
    std::cout << "Copy Assignment" << '\n'; // <- This is NEVER printed
    delete[] data;
    data = new char[strlen(s.data)+1];
    strcpy(data, s.data);
    return *this;
}

int main(){
    String s1 ("Hello");
    String s2 ("World");

    s2 = s1;   // This should call the overloaded copy assignment operator!?

    std::cout << s2.showData() << '\n'; // prints "Hello"

    return 0;
}
```

or as other suggested:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

class String{
   public:
        String() : data {new char[1]} { std::cout << "Empty Ctor\n" << '\n'; }
        String(const char* s):data{new char[strlen(s)]}{ strcpy (data, s); std::cout << "Args Ctor\n"; }
        String& operator=(const String&);
        char* showData(){ return data; }
   private:
         char* data;
};

String& String::operator=(const String& s){
    std::cout << "Copy Assignment" << '\n'; // <- This is NEVER printed
    delete[] data;
    data = new char[strlen(s.data)+1];
    strcpy(data, s.data);
    return *this;
}

int main(){
    String* s1 = new String("Hello");
    String* s2 = new String("World");

    *s2 = *s1;   // This should call the overloaded copy assignment operator!?

    std::cout << s2->showData() << '\n'; // prints "Hello"

    return 0;
}
```

This is reason why you should learn C and pointers before you start messing around with pointers in C++.

Comment: String(const char* s):data{new char[strlen(s)]}{ strcpy (data, s); std::cout << "Args Ctor\n"; } on your example am not sure if this line will compile, copying a const char* to a non-const char*

Comment: @gath it compiles on my machine. if you have keyword constant in front of function argument that means that the function will not change parameter. In my case I am copying constant `char *` array but I am doing it character by character (that is how `strcpy()` works.

Comment: @gath: Copying a const thing to a non-const thing works just fine. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning a pointer to another pointer. Do this:

```
*s2 = *s1;
```

Comment: When I change to this, nothing gets printed.

Comment: @gath your code has few compilation errors. you need to fix them first.

Comment: sorry typo, should be: String(const char* s): data{(char *)s}{std::cout << "Args Ctor"; }

Comment: @gath: and your Args Ctor needs some changes :D. Use `strlen` and `strcpy`